# Writing line to a file using C

Tags: c, file-io

I'm currently doing this:

```
FILE *fOut;
fOut = fopen("fileOut.txt", "w");
char line[255];
...
strcat(line, "\n");
fputs(line, fOut);
```

but find that when I open the file in a text editor I get

```
line 1

line 2
```

If I remove the strcat(line, "\n"); then I get.

```
line 1line2
```

How do I get fOut to be

```
line 1
line 2
```

Comment: Just curious: how are you populating `line` before appending the newline?

Comment: Define "I get". How are you analysing the file contents?

Comment: @torrentialcoding I'm actually looping through a file encrypting each line and then writing that line to a new file.

Answer (score 4):

The `puts()` function appends a newline to the string it is given to write to `stdout`; the `fputs()` function does not do that.

Since you've not shown us all the code, we can only hypothesize about what you've done.  But:

```
strcpy(line, "line1");
fputs(line, fOut);
putc('\n', fOut);
strcpy(line, "line2\n");
fputs(line, fOut);
```

would produce the result you require, in two slightly different ways that could each be used twice to achieve consistency (and your code should be consistent — leave 'elegant variation' for your literature writing, not for your programming).

---

In a comment, you say:

> I'm actually looping through a file encrypting each line and then writing that line to a new file.

Oh boy!  Are you base-64 encoding the encrypted data?  If not, then:

1. You must include `b` in the `fopen()` mode (as in `fOut = fopen("fileout.bin", "wb");`) because encrypted data is binary data, not text data.  This (the `b`) is safe for both Unix and Windows, but is critical on Windows and immaterial on Unix.
2. You must not use `fputs()` to write the data; there will be zero bytes (`'\0'`) amongst the encrypted values and `fputs()` will stop at the first of those that it encounters.  You probably need to use `fwrite()` instead, telling it exactly how many bytes to write each time.
3. You must not insert newlines anywhere; the encrypted data might contain newlines, but those must be preserved, and no extraneous one can be added.
4. When you read this file back in, you must open it as a binary file `"rb"` and read it using `fread()`.

If you are base-64 encoding your encrypted data, then you can go back to treating the output as text; that's the point of base-64 encoding.

Comment: @Dunc: You could not be less useful than just saying "this didn't work". **What happened? *What did you observe?***

Answer (score 3):

When files are opened with `w` (or `wt`) Windows replaces the `\n` with `\r\n`.

To avoid this, open the file with `wb` (instead of `w`).

```
...
fOut = fopen("fileOut.txt", "wb");
...
```

Unlike many other OSs, Windows makes a distinction between binary and text mode, and -- confusingly -- the Windows C runtime handles both modes differently.

Comment: Just to add to this, `fputs` already appends a new line, so there is no need to explicitly add one.

Comment: @Mike Kwan: Thank you for your comment. I believe you meant `puts` appends a newline. AFAICT `fputs` does not. Link: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/puts/

Comment: @MikeKwan: No; `puts()` appends a newline; `fputs()` does not append a newline.  Similarly, `gets()` removes a newline; `fgets()` does not remove a newline.

Comment: This didn't solve the problem and to confirm I am using windows but will be porting to unix in the future.

Comment: @Adam Bernier, Jonathan Leffler, yeah I was thinking of `puts` :P

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `\r` instead of `\n`.  What platform are you running this on, Windows?